# SVG animation triggering on load rather than on DOM insertion

Tags: javascript, svg

The code below animates a SVG circle changing color and works as expected.

If the call to `SVG.addAnimatedCircle(this.root)` is made from within the `callback` method (instead of where it is below, inside the `constructor`), the animation starts when the document is loaded — and is therefore invisible unless the window is clicked — rather than when the event is triggered.

```js
class SVG {

    constructor() {
        const root = document.createElementNS(
            'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
        root.setAttribute('viewBox', '-50 -50 100 100');
        this.root = root;

        this.callback = this.callback.bind(this);
        window.addEventListener('click', this.callback);

        SVG.addAnimatedCircle(this.root);
    }

    callback() {
        // SVG.addAnimatedCircle(this.root);
    }

    static addAnimatedCircle(toElement) {
        const el = document.createElementNS(
            'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
        el.setAttribute('cx', '0');
        el.setAttribute('cy', '0');
        el.setAttribute('r', '10');
        el.setAttribute('fill', 'red');

        toElement.appendChild(el);

        const anim = document.createElementNS(
            'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'animate');
        anim.setAttribute('attributeName', 'fill');
        anim.setAttribute('from', 'blue');
        anim.setAttribute('to', 'red');
        anim.setAttribute('dur', '3s');

        el.appendChild(anim);  
    }   
    
}

const svg = new SVG();
document.body.appendChild(svg.root);
```

(The above doesn't need to be inside a `class` of course, I'm simplifying a more complex class).

Why is that? Isn't the animation supposed to start when the element is created and added to the DOM?

Comment: It rather depends on whether any other animation runs that moves the timeline along.

Comment: There is no other animation involved. This is why I've simplified my class into a minimal standalone example demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Interesting observation. I've added simplified testcase with static SVG and alert fired from script immediately "after" SVG node: in my Firefox it displays black non-animated circle under modal. Chrome waits until alert is dismissed to draw (and animate) the SVG and subsequent alert pauses animation (unlike Firefox).

Comment: Well kinda, but this time it is not the issue in question, quite opposite: I've deliberately used alert to postpone load event and see how the SVG looks and behaves "before load" / with main thread paused.
BTW, running the testcase few times I got red circle (state without animation) once, so it seems like a nice race condition. (I have no deep insight how/whether JS thread, HTML render and SVG SMIL timers relates to each other, just wanted to add the sample to play with.)

Comment: (But yes, it's just a wild guess that my testcase demonstrates exactly OP's problem.  If so, I suppose the answer will most likely be "do not expect your SVG to animate before the document is fully loaded and main (JS) thread is idle.", but again, I'm not a browser maker to prove that.)

Comment: @myf it's really better not to guess. I think we should rollback your edit and see if the OP can clarify the problem first. The animation should start when the element is added to the DOM in both of the OPs scenarios, and it does in Firefox.

Comment: Well, the title of this question is "SVG animation triggering on load rather than on DOM insertion", so I guess now OP have to embed MWE of his gradually loading app that to show us "on load" vs "DOM insertion" difference they are referring to.  It's true that there are many things that delays "on load" (immediately called alert being probably most convenient of them all to simulate), but it'd be a surprise if this precise detail really mattered.

Comment: As for "The animation should start when the element is added to the DOM" - so you have seen the animation running in the rolled-back testcase under the initial alert modal in Firefox? I did not: for me it was frozen, in most cases in the "black" (animated) state.

Comment: I don't have a gradually loading app. The problem is much simpler than that. My original code can be copied and pasted as is and will clearly demonstrate the issue, no additional components necessary. However, after much searching, it turns out that the code was missing something crucial: `anim.setAttribute('begin', 'indefinite')` to delay the animation start, and `document.querySelector('animate').beginElement()` (inside the callback). The `beginElement` method then triggers the animation when the event is fired. Should I make this the answer?

Comment: Your example loads and immediately animates in all browsers I've tried without any alterations, so for me it does not seem "broken" in it's current state (SVG element with SMIL animation appended to the DOM with JS immediately). If you have seen it "paused" while your app loaded, there must have been anything else going on. Could you reproduce it in code sample?

Comment: The code indeed animates immediately. Please read the rest of my post. If you add the circle element in the *callback* instead (where it's currently commented out), then the animation runs when the document loads, *not* when the callback is called. As I wrote above, apparently the solution is to use a 'indefinite' begin value.

Comment: Yes, I think I see it now; basically you append *empty* SVG to DOM first, and after that insert content with animation into it (on click) and the animation seem already finished because the root SVG's timer is beyond the implied `begin="0s"` of the animation.

Comment: @RobertLongson is this the reading made by Firefox? From https://svgwg.org/specs/animations/#RelationshipToSMILAnimation I read "the document begin for a given SVG document fragment is defined to be the exact time at which the ‘svg’ element's load event is triggered", which would mean that the timeline doesn't need an actual <animate> to run, simply having the <svg> in the doc should start it, and it seems to be Chrome's behavior. In your opinion, where should the issue be opened?

Comment: @kaiido The timeline doesn't advance unless there are animations running. If you uncomment the line in the OPs testcase so there are two animations then the first will run and the seccond in the callback will be added at a non-zero animation time hence my first comment.

Comment: @RobertLongson yes, I saw Firefox behavior. My question is are you sure this is how it "should" behave? From the specs excerpt I quoted it is said that the timeline should advance as soon as the <svg>'s `load` event is fired, which itself should happen as soon as the element is in the DOM and all its content is loaded (since there is nothing to be loaded in OP's case, that would be as soon as the element is appended). Chrome does this. Firefox doesn't. My take would be that this is a Firefox bug, but your comment seems to imply that my reading of the specs and Chrome's behavior are both wrong.

Comment: @RobertLongson https://jsfiddle.net/8zfjb1o5/ In Chrome and Safari will output ~ `2.0000...` in FF `0`.

Comment: @Kaiido Take it up with [w3c](https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues) perhaps

Comment: @RobertLongson I'd like to, but to do so I need to have an argument against Chrome's behavior.  To me that behavior is in accordance to my reading of the specs, I don't see how I can blame the specs for writing something that makes sense and that is understood by 2/3 of the browsers to mean what I also do understand. So I'd rather open an FF bug, but you seem to imply you don't believe this is an FF bug either. I guess one of FF devs should open that specs issue if you find the specs are unclear.

Comment: @Kaiido I think we don't run the timeline as an optimisation. I think we've talked to Chrome about this but they've been non-commital. I don't think we'd want to change.

Comment: What seems strange is that adding second SVG containing `animate` element to @Kaiido's jsbin makes the first (empty) SVG suddenly report same currentTime as later (in Firefox). (https://jsfiddle.net/myfonj/j01qatpu/8/) That really feels counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<animate>` element you create will have its `begin` attribute computed to `0s` (since unset).
This `0s` value is relative to the "document begin time", which itself in this HTML document corresponds to the root `<svg>`'s current time.

This means that if you do create such an `<animate>` element after its root `<svg>` element has been in the DOM, its animation state will depend on how long the root `<svg>` element has been in the DOM:

```js
const root = document.querySelector("svg");
const circles = document.querySelectorAll("circle");
const duration = 3;
// will fully animate
circles[0].append(makeAnimate());

// will produce only half of the animation
setTimeout(() => {
  circles[1].append(makeAnimate());
}, duration * 500);

// will not animate
setTimeout(() => {
  circles[2].append(makeAnimate());
}, duration * 1000);

function makeAnimate() {
  const anim = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "animate");
  anim.setAttribute("attributeName", "fill");
  anim.setAttribute("from", "blue");
  anim.setAttribute("to", "red");
  anim.setAttribute("fill", "freeze");
  anim.setAttribute("dur", duration + "s");
  return anim;
}
```

```css
circle { fill: blue }
```

```html
<svg height="60">
  <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="25"/>
  <circle cx="90" cy="30" r="25"/>
  <circle cx="150" cy="30" r="25"/>
</svg>
<p>left circle starts immediately, and fully animates</p>
<p>middle circle starts after <code>duration / 2</code> and matches the same position as left circle</p>
<p>right circle starts after <code>duration</code>, the animation is already completed by then, nothing "animates"</p>
```

We can set the `<svg>`'s current time trough its [`SVGSVGElement.setCurrentTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGSVGElement#methods) method.
So to create an `<animate>` that would start at the time it got created, no matter when it is, we could use this, however, **this will also affect all the other `<animate>` that are already in the `<svg>`**:

```js
const root = document.querySelector("svg");
const circles = document.querySelectorAll("circle");
const duration = 3;

circles[0].append(makeAnimate());
root.setCurrentTime(0); // reset <animate> time

setTimeout(() => {
  circles[1].append(makeAnimate());
  root.setCurrentTime(0); // reset <animate> time
}, duration * 500);

setTimeout(() => {
  circles[2].append(makeAnimate());
  root.setCurrentTime(0); // reset <animate> time
}, duration * 1000);

function makeAnimate() {
  const anim = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "animate");
  anim.setAttribute("attributeName", "fill");
  anim.setAttribute("from", "blue");
  anim.setAttribute("to", "red");
  anim.setAttribute("fill", "freeze");
  anim.setAttribute("dur", duration + "s");
  return anim;
}
```

```css
circle { fill: blue }
```

```html
<svg height="60">
  <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="25"/>
  <circle cx="90" cy="30" r="25"/>
  <circle cx="150" cy="30" r="25"/>
</svg>
```

So, while it may do for some users, in most cases it's probably better to instead set only the `<animate>`'s `begin` attribute.
Luckily, we can also get the current time, with the [`SVGSVGElement.getCurrentTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGSVGElement#methods) method.

```js
const root = document.querySelector("svg");
const circles = document.querySelectorAll("circle");
const duration = 3;

circles[0].append(makeAnimate());

setTimeout(() => {
  circles[1].append(makeAnimate());
}, duration * 500);

setTimeout(() => {
  circles[2].append(makeAnimate());
}, duration * 1000);

function makeAnimate() {
  const anim = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "animate");
  anim.setAttribute("attributeName", "fill");
  anim.setAttribute("from", "blue");
  anim.setAttribute("to", "red");
  anim.setAttribute("fill", "freeze");
  anim.setAttribute("dur", duration + "s");
  // set the `begin` to "now"
  anim.setAttribute("begin", root.getCurrentTime() + "s");
  return anim;
}
```

```css
circle { fill: blue }
```

```html
<svg height="60">
  <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="25"/>
  <circle cx="90" cy="30" r="25"/>
  <circle cx="150" cy="30" r="25"/>
</svg>
```

But the way we usually do this is to use the API fully and control it all through JS, since you already did start using JS.
To do so, we set the `begin` attribute to "indefinite", so that it doesn't start automatically, and then we call the [SVGAnimateElement (`<animate>`)'s `beginElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimationElement#methods) method, which will start the animation manually, when we want:

```js
const root = document.querySelector("svg");
const circles = document.querySelectorAll("circle");
const duration = 3;

{
  const animate = makeAnimate();
  circles[0].appendChild(animate);
  animate.beginElement();
}

setTimeout(() => {
  const animate = makeAnimate();
  circles[1].appendChild(animate);
  animate.beginElement();
}, duration * 500);

setTimeout(() => {
  const animate = makeAnimate();
  circles[2].appendChild(animate);
  animate.beginElement();
}, duration * 1000);

function makeAnimate() {
  const anim = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "animate");
  anim.setAttribute("attributeName", "fill");
  anim.setAttribute("from", "blue");
  anim.setAttribute("to", "red");
  anim.setAttribute("fill", "freeze");
  anim.setAttribute("dur", duration + "s");
  // set the `begin` to "manual"
  anim.setAttribute("begin", "indefinite");
  return anim;
}
```

```css
circle { fill: blue }
```

```html
<svg height="60">
  <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="25"/>
  <circle cx="90" cy="30" r="25"/>
  <circle cx="150" cy="30" r="25"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is indeed the solution I've mentioned in the comments to my question, and proposed to write as an answer. Thank you for presenting all the options.

Comment: @Cirrocumulus yes, I read your comment only after I composed this answer, indeed you found the (I-believe-to-be) best solution (beginElement()).

Answer (score 0):

(Not the answer, just presentation of the problem for possible accomodation into the question and/or proper answer [suggested by OP in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69367827/svg-animation-triggering-on-load-rather-than-on-dom-insertion#comment122608523_69367827).

```html
<style>svg {outline: #0FF6 solid; outline-offset: -2px;}</style>

<table role="presentation" border><tr><td>

1. Static SVG with animated circle:

<td>

<svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" width="30" height="30">
 <circle r="40" fill="black">
  <animate begin="0.5s" fill="freeze" attributeName="fill" from="blue" to="red" dur="5s"></animate>
 </circle>
</svg> 

<tr><td>

2. Empty SVG, 

<button onclick='
 emptySVG.innerHTML = document.querySelector("circle").outerHTML;
'>Put similar animated circle into it</button>:

<td>

<svg id="emptySVG" viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" width="30" height="30">
 <!-- empty -->
</svg>

<tr><td>

3. <button onclick='
 sampleCell.innerHTML = document.querySelector("svg").outerHTML
'>Create new SVG with animated circle</button>:

<td id="sampleCell">
(here.)

</table>

<p>
<button onclick="location.reload()">Reload page</button>
<button onclick="
[...document.querySelectorAll('animate')].forEach(a=>{
  //a.setAttribute('begin','indefinite'); // does not seem to be necessary
  a.beginElement();
 })
">Reset all animations</button>
```

Putting animated circle to second SVG produces state that corresponds with already elapsed duration in existing empty SVG: it matches the first one, so it either runs in sync or is finished. Goal is to run the animation upon circle's appearance.